# How to prevent page jump when using # href to swap gallery images using a div ID?

Tags: css, html, hash, gallery, href

I have been struggling with a problem for a while now. I've made a simple html gallery using CSS and a # href to essentially swap out different div ID's containing gallery images. The problem is that when you select the "next" or "previous" buttons in the gallery it jumps the page up in the browser so the gallery is aligned at the top of the page. Does anybody have any ideas how to prevent this?

Here is what the code for the gallery looks like:

```
<div id="pic1">
<img src="click/pic1.jpg" alt="" />
<a class="previous" href="#pic10"><b>Previous</b></a><a class="next" href="#pic2"><b>Next</b></a>
</div>
<div id="pic2">
<img src="click/pic2.jpg" alt="" />
<a class="previous" href="#pic1"><b>Previous</b></a><a class="next" href="#pic3"> <b>Next</b></a>
</div>
<div id="pic3">
<img src="click/pic3.jpg" alt="" />
<a class="previous" href="#pic2"><b>Previous</b></a><a class="next" href="#pic4"><b>Next</b></a>
</div>
<div id="pic4">
<img src="click/pic4.jpg" alt="" />
<a class="previous" href="#pic3"><b>Previous</b></a><a class="next" href="#pic5">  <b>Next</b></a>
</div>
<div id="pic5">
<img src="click/pic5.jpg" alt="" />
<a class="previous" href="#pic4"><b>Previous</b></a><a class="next" href="#pic6"><b>Next</b></a>
</div>
<div id="pic6">
<img src="click/pic6.jpg" alt="" />
<a class="previous" href="#pic5"><b>Previous</b></a><a class="next" href="#pic7"><b>Next</b></a>
</div>
<div id="pic7">
<img src="click/pic7.jpg" alt="" />
<a class="previous" href="#pic6"><b>Previous</b></a><a class="next" href="#pic8"><b>Next</b></a>
</div>
<div id="pic8">
<img src="click/pic8.jpg" alt="" />
<a class="previous" href="#pic7"><b>Previous</b></a><a class="next" href="#pic9"><b>Next</b></a>
</div>
<div id="pic9">
<img src="click/pic9.jpg" alt="" />
<a class="previous" href="#pic8"><b>Previous</b></a><a class="next" href="#pic10"><b>Next</b></a>
</div>
<div id="pic10">
<img src="click/pic10.jpg" alt="" />
<a class="previous" href="#pic9"><b>Previous</b></a><a class="next" href="#pic1">  <b>Next</b></a>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use JQuery after you set

```
<a class="previous" href="javascript:void(0);">Next</a>
```

then call the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a.previous').click(function(e){
        var picID= parseInt($(this).parent().attr("id").substr(3));//gets the pic id count
        $("#pic"+(picID)).hide(); //hide the current div
        $("#pic"+(picID-1)).show(); //show the previous div
    });

    $('a.next').click(function(e){
        var picID= parseInt($(this).parent().attr("id").substr(3)); //gets the pic id count
        $("#pic"+(picID)).hide(); //hide the current div
        $("#pic"+(picID+1)).show(); //show the previous div
    });

});
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/uZ6g5/

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, unfortunately I'm still struggling a little bit. Normally I would declare my java in the head of my document, I'm not entirely sure how to "call" that javascript afterwards? I'm assuming I would be saving the java in a separate java file? Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: This works now: http://jsfiddle.net/uZ6g5/3/ but where on my html page would I place the Java portion of the code? Thanks!!

Comment: You can refer to the jQuery tutorial [Getting Started with jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of linking to #, link to javascript:void(0);

```
<a class="previous" href="javascript:void(0);">Next</a>
```

Or, prevent the default event with Javascript

```
$("a.previous, a.next").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! If I were to use the javascript:void method, how would the browser know to load in the next/previous Div ID?

Comment: I've tried both the suggestions above and neither seem to be working for me. The first solution doesn't tell the gallery to go to the next "slide" at all, and the second one didn't seem to make a difference (I used the java code in the head of the html page wrapped in a text type javascript tag, any ideas?!! Thanks!

Comment: Neither of those lines tell it to go to the next slide, they simply tell the page not to scroll up. If you would like some help with going to the next slide, please post your full page in a JSFiddle.